# 404 for web.api cors OPTIONS

Tags: c#, asp.net, http, asp.net-web-api, cors

I've followed the usual steps for enabling cors in web.api, but get a 404 response to an OPTIONS request in Chrome and in Firefox I get `Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://api.mydomain.com/api/1/widgets. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.`

In my WebApiConfig.cs I've got:

```
var enableCorsAttribute = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");
config.EnableCors(enableCorsAttribute);
```

I've also tried adding `EnableCors` attributes to the specific controllers or actions and all have the same result.

I've also added the following to my web.config:

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
  <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
</modules>
<handlers>
    <remove name="WebDAV" />
...
```

Here is my javascript:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://api.mydomain.com/api/1/widgets',
    type: "GET",
    headers: {
        Accept: "text/html; charset=utf-8",
        Authorization: 'Bearer ???????????????????????????????'
            }
        });
```

But the response is 404 in Chrome and "Cross-Origin request Blocked" in Firefox.

Here are the details of the failing request from my chrome developer toolbar:

```
Remote Address:??.???.???.???:443
Request URL:https://api.mydomain.com/api/1/widgets
Request Method:OPTIONS
Status Code:404 Not Found
```

Request

```
OPTIONS /api/1/widgets HTTP/1.1
Host: api.mydomain.com
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
Origin: http://myotherdomain.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.143 Safari/537.36
Access-Control-Request-Headers: accept, authorization
Accept: */*
Referer: http://myotherdomain.com/
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-GB,en;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6
```

Response

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://myotherdomain.com
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
X-AspNetMvc-Version: 5.0
X-UA-Compatible: IE=edge,chrome=1
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Cache-conrol: no-store
Date: Thu, 28 Aug 2014 16:00:28 GMT
Content-Length: 341
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I answered this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53280377/193634, IIS is blocking OPTIONS verb.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In case anyone else has the same problem, this issue was due to the fact that we were using Microsoft's excellent [UrlScan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/working-with-urlscan/urlscan-3-reference) in IIS.

UrlScan has an [AllowVerbs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/working-with-urlscan/urlscan-3-reference#allowverbs-section) section and a [DenyVerbs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/working-with-urlscan/urlscan-3-reference#denyverbs-section) section.  Ensure that the options verb is allowed.

Comment: Thanks for the hint!  In my case, I had configured my routes using `MapHttpRoute` and the `OPTION` verb was not allowed because of a `System.Web.Http.Routing.HttpMethodConstraint`.

Comment: +5 this have taken my whole day, finally catch it!.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        var corsAttr = new EnableCorsAttribute("http://localhost:3000", "*", "*");
        config.EnableCors(corsAttr);

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApiWithId", "Api/{controller}/{id}", new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }, new { id = new GuidConstraint() });
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApiWithAction", "Api/{controller}/{action}");
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApiGet", "Api/{controller}", new { action = "Get" }, new { httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint(HttpMethod.Get) });
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApiPost", "Api/{controller}", new { action = "Post" }, new { httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint(HttpMethod.Post) });
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApiOptions", "Api/{controller}", new { action = "Options" }, new { httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint(HttpMethod.Options) });
    }
}
```

The last line can solve the issue for .Net WebApi