# How to enable CORS in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, cors

I am trying to enable cross origin resources sharing on my ASP.NET Core Web API, but I am stuck.

The `EnableCors` attribute accepts `policyName` of type `string` as parameter:

```cs
// Summary:
//     Creates a new instance of the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Core.EnableCorsAttribute.
//
// Parameters:
//   policyName:
//     The name of the policy to be applied.
public EnableCorsAttribute(string policyName);
```

What does the `policyName` mean and how can I configure **CORS** on an ASP.NET Core Web API?

Comment: here is the article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors

Comment: Check my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74255255/10030693

Answer (score 516, accepted):

For ASP.NET Core 6:

```
var  MyAllowSpecificOrigins = "_myAllowSpecificOrigins";

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(name: MyAllowSpecificOrigins,
                      builder =>
                      {
                          builder.WithOrigins("http://example.com",
                                              "http://www.contoso.com");
                      });
});

// services.AddResponseCaching();

builder.Services.AddControllers();

var app = builder.Build();
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();

app.UseCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins);

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

See the [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors) for more samples.

---

For ASP.NET Core 3.1 and 5.0:

You have to configure a CORS policy at application startup in the `ConfigureServices` method:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("MyPolicy", builder =>
    {
        builder.WithOrigins("http://example.com")
               .AllowAnyMethod()
               .AllowAnyHeader();
    }));

    // ...
}
```

The `CorsPolicyBuilder` in `builder` allows you to configure the policy to your needs. You can now use this name to apply the policy to controllers and actions:

```
[EnableCors("MyPolicy")]
```

Or apply it to every request:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    app.UseCors("MyPolicy");

    // ...

    // This should always be called last to ensure that
    // middleware is registered in the correct order.
    app.UseMvc();
}
```

Comment: I found that app.UseCors("MyPolicy") didn't work for my API endpoints. I needed to explicitly [EnableCors("MyPolicy")] on the controller endpoints in question.

Comment: From [the official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors#enabling-cors-with-middleware): "To enable CORS for your entire application add the CORS middleware to your request pipeline using the `UseCors` extension method. Note that the CORS middleware must precede any defined endpoints in your app that you want to support cross-origin requests (ex. before any call to `UseMvc`)."

Comment: I added app.UseCors() after app.AddMvc() and it didn't work. Because order of Use methods affects how the middleware works!

Comment: Are there any risks of allowing any origin?

Comment: This answer didn't work for me, because of missing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors nuget package.

Comment: Not need to explicitly importing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors, while I am using .net core 3.1.

Comment: I've got this error: 'EnableCorsAttribute' does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments

Comment: @robbpriestley your comment was the key to unlock this for aspnetcore2.2 after 3 days of fighting the code. Thank you! I did find that it was good enough to place the attribute on top of the controller class, saving you needing to do it for each method, if that's what you want. But crucially, NOT on the controller base class (which I tried on day 2 without thinking that was the problem!)

Comment: With AllowCredentials, only exact urls will work, like "http://localhost:49937". Without the port, this did not work.

Comment: I've tried everything every docs say, including all the code here on Net5 and nothing works - still get CORS errors trying to call my API from my WebMvc project, all on localhost. What I need, I think, is a witch doctor

Comment: My witch-doctor came through with an answer.... I needed to use/add authorization. I didn't think I used any and have such a basic site, I didn't care... and none of the docs with code mentioned that authorization is absolutely required... but without authorization... adding CORS in any way or shape, wouldnt work

Comment: To avoide names you can use AddDefaultPolicy

Comment: Using .net8.0 for my API, I found that this was the problem, but not the solution. I ended up using the following for my app:

            builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddDefaultPolicy(
                    policy =>
                    {
                        policy.AllowAnyOrigin().WithMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE");
                    });
            });

Answer (score 143):

**Applies to .NET Core 1 and .Net Core 2**

If using `.Net-Core 1.1`

Unfortunately the docs are very confusing in this specific case. So I'll make it dead-simple:

- Add `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors` nuget package to your project
- In `ConfigureServices` method, add `services.AddCors();`
- In `Configure` method, before calling `app.UseMvc()` and `app.UseStaticFiles()`, add:

  ```
   app.UseCors(builder => builder
       .AllowAnyOrigin()
       .AllowAnyMethod()
       .AllowAnyHeader()
       .AllowCredentials());
  ```

That's it. Every client has access to your ASP.NET Core Website/API.

---

If using `.Net-Core 2.0`

- Add `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors` nuget package to your project
- in `ConfigureServices` method, **before** calling `services.AddMvc()`, add:

  ```
    services.AddCors(options =>
       {
           options.AddPolicy("AllowAll",
               builder =>
               {
                   builder
                   .AllowAnyOrigin() 
                   .AllowAnyMethod()
                   .AllowAnyHeader()
                   .AllowCredentials();
               });
       });
  ```
- **(Important)** In `Configure` method, **before** calling `app.UseMvc()`, add  `app.UseCors("AllowAll");`

  `"AllowAll"` is the policy name which we need to mention in `app.UseCors`. It could be any name.

Comment: true, thought i can enable just one of them !

Comment: Thanks. I had my AddCors after UseMvc and that was causing it to not work properly. Yours is the only answer that mentions this.

Comment: This doesn't work I don't think.  When supplying credentials, you can't allow any origin.  I'm still trying to get this to work.

Comment: That's the key piece: `.UseCors()` before `.UseMvc()`

Comment: Wasted time with not knowing about UseCors before UserMvc... thanks for the help!

Comment: @JasonGoemaat As of .NET Core 2.2 you cannot use both `AllowAnyOrigin` and`AllowCredentials`: https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/3106 - you may only use one or the other.

Comment: Nothing is working, i tried all options and it's still being blocked by CORS. If i call my own server at localhost, it gets the value.

Comment: Is this solution only for Web API or does it also work with MVC?

Comment: @Ali123 I can't test this right now but this used to be the solution for ASP.NET Core 1 and 2 versions (It's clearly mentioned in the answer)

Comment: In my case I was not using .UseMvc() but .UseRouting() and I have had to add app.UseCors("AllowAll"); AFTER the .UseRouting().

Answer (score 51):

Based on [Henk's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31942128/4320665) I have been able to come up with the specific domain, the method I want to allow and also the header I want to enable CORS for:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddCors(options =>
         options.AddPolicy("AllowSpecific", p => p.WithOrigins("http://localhost:1233")
                                                   .WithMethods("GET")
                                                   .WithHeaders("name")));
    services.AddMvc();
}
```

usage:

```
[EnableCors("AllowSpecific")]
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: `To critique or request clarification from an author` I don't think that's the case here and Henk's answer have been marked already. My answer was an add-on if you want to allow specific domains.

Comment: Something is missing in your code, 'IServiceCollection' does not contain a definition for 'ConfigureCors'. Please check it and try to give a complete answer.

Comment: @Sami-L Please check my updated answer. I found out that `ConfigureCors` was changed to `AddCors`.

Comment: this worked well for me for .netcoreapp2.2

Answer (score 48):

Got this working with **.NET Core 3.1** as follows

1. Make sure you place the `UseCors` code between `app.UseRouting();` and `app.UseAuthentication();`

```cs
app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseRouting();
app.UseCors("CorsApi");

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => {
    endpoints.MapControllers();
});
```

2. Then place this code in the `ConfigureServices` method

```cs
services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("CorsApi",
        builder => builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200", "http://mywebsite.com")
            .AllowAnyHeader()
            .AllowAnyMethod());
});
```

3. And above the base controller I placed this

```cs
[EnableCors("CorsApi")]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class BaseController : ControllerBase
```

Now all my controllers will inherit from the `BaseController` and will have CORS enabled

Comment: Things werent working for me until I `place the UseCors code between app.UseRouting(); and app.UseAuthentication();`

Comment: Nobody mentioned except @tfa that position of the UseCors code must be between app.UseRouting(); and app.UseAuthentication();  It's matter!

Comment: CORS didn't work for me until I got to know that the order of calls matters. Thanks! 

Comment: Do I still need to add the attribute if I use the default policy? FYI, I have tested as `[EnableCors]` and in .Net 5.

Comment: @0014 - thank you so much, you're the only one that even helped at all getting this to work for me. These required order method calls seem pretty bad design. I understand why they work that way, but damn does it suck.

Comment: thanks for saving time. The only full answer here.

Comment: love how everybody says something else about where to place .UseCors()

Answer (score 17):

**If you are hosting on IIS**, one possible reason for encountering this issue is that IIS might be blocking the `OPTIONS` verb.

One telltale indication is you are getting `404` error during `OPTIONS` request.

To fix this, you need to explicitly tell IIS **not** to block `OPTIONS` request.

**Go to Request Filtering:**

[image: IIS Request Filtering]

**Make sure OPTIONS is allowed:**

[image: Make sure OPTIONS is True]

**Or, just create a `web.config` with the following setting:**

```
<system.webServer>
    <security>
        <requestFiltering>
            <verbs>
                <remove verb="OPTIONS" />
                <add verb="OPTIONS" allowed="true" />
            </verbs>
        </requestFiltering>
    </security>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. I tried everything on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-3.1#enable-cors-with-endpoint-routing and yet i was getting only CORS errors. Until somebody pointed out your answer... I wonder why the people at MS didn´t care to include this little tip on their guide.

Answer (score 17):

Specifically in dotnet core 2.2 with SignalR you must change

`.WithOrigins("http://localhost:3000")` or

`.SetIsOriginAllowed(isOriginAllowed: _ => true) //for all origins`

instead `.AllowAnyOrigin()` with `.AllowCredentials()`

https://trailheadtechnology.com/breaking-change-in-aspnetcore-2-2-for-signalr-and-cors/

https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/4483

Comment: Using SignalR in a .NET Core console app and this is the only working solution for my scenario.

Answer (score 13):

you have three ways to enable CORS:

- In **middleware** using a named policy or default policy.
- Using **endpoint** routing.
- With the **[EnableCors]** attribute.

**Enable CORS with named policy:**

```
public class Startup
{
    readonly string CorsPolicy = "_corsPolicy";

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy(name: CorsPolicy,
                              builder =>
                              {
                                 builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                                      .AllowAnyMethod()
                                      .AllowAnyHeader()
                                      .AllowCredentials();
                              });
        });

        // services.AddResponseCaching();
        services.AddControllers();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseCors(CorsPolicy);

        // app.UseResponseCaching();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }
}
```

> **UseCors** must be called before **UseResponseCaching** when using **UseResponseCaching**.

**Enable CORS with default policy:**

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddDefaultPolicy(
                builder =>
                {
                     builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                                      .AllowAnyMethod()
                                      .AllowAnyHeader()
                                      .AllowCredentials();
                });
        });

        services.AddControllers();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseCors();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }
}
```

**Enable CORS with endpoint**

```
public class Startup
{
    readonly string CorsPolicy = "_corsPolicy ";

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy(name: CorsPolicy,
                              builder =>
                              {
                                  builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                                      .AllowAnyMethod()
                                      .AllowAnyHeader()
                                      .AllowCredentials();
                              });
        });

        services.AddControllers();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseCors();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers()
                     .RequireCors(CorsPolicy)
        });
    }
}
```

**Enable CORS with attributes**

you have two options

- **[EnableCors]** specifies the default policy.
- **[EnableCors("{Policy String}")]** specifies a named policy.

Comment: It sucks you can't configure CORS without compiling. If your client changes it's address, you have to go through a rebuild process and redeployment. MS didn't think too hard about this.

Comment: I have done all the code you listed here for the "default policy" on my web mvc and api projects - all running on localhost and still get a CORS error calling the api from the mvc app

Comment: I also added the `[EnableCors]` attribute on the offending API call, I still get a CORS error, there must be something else at play here

Comment: Same here. Nothing in this page works. Unbelievable!!!

Answer (score 9):

> You have to configure in Startup.cs class

```
services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
                builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowCredentials());
        });
```

Answer (score 7):

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddCors(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("AllowAnyOrigin",
            builder => builder
            .AllowAnyOrigin()
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .AllowAnyHeader());
    });

    services.Configure<MvcOptions>(options => {
        options.Filters.Add(new CorsAuthorizationFilterFactory("AllowAnyOrigin"));
    });            
}
```

Comment: Wonderful way to circumvent the already deployed browser security. Just don't!

Comment: I don't think this should be down-voted.  This is an "alternate" way.  You can either use the "UseCors()" method or else add a global MVC filter like what Nathan did here.

Comment: this works for me on .net core 2.2 plus adding app.UseCors("AllowAnyOrigin"); in "Configure" method

Comment: It's important to "Add Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors nuget package to your project". Thank you for mention it!

Comment: @JoshMouch for every serious project there's a guy with 5 users in an office who just need their local-hosted, internal-network API to work *now* without giving a hoot about CORS

Answer (score 7):

For Web API(ASP.Net core 6.0)
In Program.cs just add before builder.Build();

```
builder.Services.AddCors(p => p.AddPolicy("corsapp", builder =>
{
    builder.WithOrigins("*").AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader();
}));
```

also add

```
app.UseCors("corsapp");
```

Answer (score 3):

**For ASP.NET Core Web API 5**

In ConfigureServices add `services.AddCors();` Before `services.AddControllers();`

Add UseCors in Configure

```
app.UseCors(x => x
.AllowAnyOrigin()
.AllowAnyMethod()
.AllowAnyHeader());
```

Comment: I've done exactly all this and I still get CORS error in the browser

Comment: For ASP.NET Core Web API 5

Comment: BTW my problem was that my url didn't have "http://" I just used the local machine name I was connecting to, which usually worked for other stuff, but not for CORS - doh

Answer (score 2):

In case you get the error "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource." Specifically for **PUT** and **DELETE** requests, you could try to disable WebDAV on IIS.

Apparently, the WebDAVModule is enabled by default and is disabling PUT and DELETE requests by default.

To disable the WebDAVModule, add this to your web.config:

```xml
<system.webServer>
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="false">
    <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
  </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Thank you!
I didn't know it would work for me on localhost but not in production.

Answer (score 2):

### Simple solution

DEVELOPMENT MODE ONLY!

```cs
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseCors(p => p.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

All the workaround mentioned above may work or may not work, in most cases it will not work. I have given the solution here

[Currently I am working on Angular and Web API(.net Core) and came across CORS issue explained below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57060019/currently-i-am-working-on-angular-and-web-api-net-core-and-came-across-cors-is)

The solution provided above will always work. With 'OPTIONS' request it is really necessary to enable 'Anonymous Authentication'. With the solution mentioned here you don't have to do all the steps mentioned above, like IIS settings.

Anyways someone marked my above post as duplicate with this post, but I can see that this post is only to enable CORS in ASP.net Core, but my post is related to, Enabling and implementing CORS in ASP.net Core and Angular.

Answer (score 0):

Some troubleshooting tips, after I managed to waste two hours on the most trivial CORS issue:

1. If you see `CORS policy execution failed` logged... Don't assume that your CORS policy is not executing properly. In fact, the CORS middleware works, and your policy is executing properly. The only thing this badly worded message means is that the request's origin doesn't match any of the allowed origins ([see source](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/461c4ece84ef5e7385249994645a3262717d3ca5/src/Middleware/CORS/src/Infrastructure/CorsService.cs#L261)), i.e. the request is disallowed.
2. The origin check (as of ASP.NET Core 5.0) happens in a very simple way... i.e. case-sensitive ordinal string comparison ([see source](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/461c4ece84ef5e7385249994645a3262717d3ca5/src/Middleware/CORS/src/Infrastructure/CorsPolicy.cs#L179)) between the strings you provided via `WithOrigins()` and what exists in `HttpContext.Request.Headers[Origin]`.
3. CORS can fail if you set an allowed origin with a trailing slash `/`, or if it contains uppercase letters. *(In my case I did in fact accidentally copy the host with a trailing slash.)*

Answer (score 0):

This Cover each endpoint . if you want block some endpoint use this annotation [DisableCors]
it well described here.

 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-5.0

1. Add `app.usecors(policyName)` Between `app.authentication()` and `app.routing()` If you are using `app.usMvc()` above it.Inside the Configure Method.
2. Inside the configureService Method

```
services.AddCors(options => options.AddPolicy(name: mypolicy,     builder =>     { builder.AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyOrigin(); }));
```

3. In Each controller add  `[EnableCors("mypolicy")]`

```
        [EnableCors("mypolicy")] 
        [Route("api/[controller]")] [ApiController] 
        public class MyController : ControllerBase
```

eg:-

```
  namespace CompanyApi2
        {
            public class Startup
            {
                public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
                {
                    Configuration = configuration;
                }
        
                public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
        
                // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this //method to add services to the container.
                public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
                {
                    services.AddCors(options =>
                        options.AddPolicy(name: mypolicy,
                            builder =>
                            {
                                builder.AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod()
                                    .AllowAnyOrigin();
                            })); //add this
                    services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
                    services.AddScoped<IDatarepository, DatabaseRepository>();
                }
        
                public string mypolicy = "mypolicy";
        
                // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
                public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
                {
                    if (env.IsDevelopment())
                    {
                        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        app.UseHsts();
                    }
        
                    app.UseCors(mypolicy); //add this
                    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
                    app.UseMvc();
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Lately when hosting the web app server on azure web app, had to edit azure app cors settings to resolve the matter (code only did not solve the issue)

1. Less secured - Enable Access-Control-Allow-Credentials -leave it blank and add * as an allowed origin
2. Mark Enable Access-Control-Allow-Credentials and then add the domains you want to allow the requests from

Answer (score 0):

Got this working with .Net Core 3.1 as follows:

In `ConfigureServices()` method:

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
  {
   ...
   services.AddCors();
   ...
  }
```

In `Configure()` method:

```
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
  {
   ...
   app.UseCors(builder =>
          builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
          .AllowAnyHeader()
          .AllowAnyMethod()
        );
   ...
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

for .Net CORE 3.1 use:

```
app.UseCors(x => x.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader())
```

Answer (score 0):

pay attantion that "/" in the end -  will block the CORS origin

```
builder.WithOrigins("http://example.com/","http://localhost:55233/");
```

will block

use

```
builder.WithOrigins("http://example.com","http://localhost:55233");
```

Answer (score 0):

**For "C# - ASP Net Core Web API (Net Core 3.1 LTS)", it worked for me ...**

In **Startup.cs** file:

Inside "**ConfigureServices**" function add this code:

```
services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
        builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
        .AllowAnyMethod()
        .AllowAnyHeader());
});
```

Note: In case of "**CorsPolicy**" you can change for what you like or use global variable in "Startup" class.

Inside "**Configure**" function add this code:

```
app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
```

Check the call order of the functions, it should look like this:

```
if (env.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllers();
});
```

And finally in your controller class add this code above your functions http:

```
[EnableCors("CorsPolicy")]
```

For example:

```
[EnableCors("CorsPolicy")]
[HttpPost("UserLoginWithGoogle")]
public async Task<ActionResult<Result>> UserLoginWithGoogle([FromBody] TokenUser tokenUser)
{            
    Result result = await usersGoogleHW.UserLoginWithGoogle(tokenUser.Token);
    return new JsonResult(result);
}
```

Note: "CorsPolicy" must match in the Startup and Controller.

Good luck ...

Answer (score 0):

this code is working my asp.net core api project.

```
<system.webServer>
  <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
  <ModSecurity enabled="false" configFile="C:\inetpub\wwwroot\owasp_crs\modsecurity.conf" />
  .
  .
  .
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?

Answer (score 0):

Having set `anonymousAuthentication: true` in a file `launchSettings.json`, it started working for me:

```
"iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": true,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:44300/",
      "sslPort": 0
    }
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

Step 1: We need Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors package in our project. For installing go to Tools -> NuGet Package Manager -> Manage NuGet Packages for Solution. Search for Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors and install the package.

Step 2: We need to inject CORS into the container so that it can be used by the application. In Startup.cs class, let’s go to the ConfigureServices method and register CORS.

[image]

So, in our server app, let’s go to Controllers -> HomeController.cs and add the EnableCors decorator to the Index method (Or your specific controller and action):

[image]

For More Detail [Click Here](http://shebin.tech/enabling-cors-in-asp-net-core/)

Comment: hey shebin, would you mind updating the URL to your blog which appears broken and inlining the code as text instead of pictures of text?

Answer (score -1):

Install nuget package `Microsoft.AspNetCore.CORS`

In `Startup.cs` under `ConfigureServices` method add the following code before `services.AddMVC()`

```
services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("AllowMyOrigin", p =>
    {
        p.AllowAnyOrigin()
            .AllowAnyHeader()
            .AllowAnyMethod();
    });
});
```

In `Startup.cs` inside the `Configure` method add `app.UseCors("AllowMyOrigin");` before you call `app.UseMvc()`

Note that when sending a request from client side remember to use https instead of http.