# Sending big string over JSON post to server with ASP.NET 5 - CORS error

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, json

I'm having the problem with sending a file as a byte array json string to the server. When the file is relatively small: up to `2MB` or so, then it works fine, but if the file is like `4MB` then the request throws error (it doesnt even reach the controller in the backend).

**Error:**

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:61416/api/organisationdocuments/.
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. 
Origin 'http://localhost:51080' is therefore not allowed access. 
The response had HTTP status code 404.
```

In the `startup.cs` I have

```
 // Add CORS support.
        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("AAPolicy", policyBuilder =>
                policyBuilder
                    .AllowAnyOrigin()
                    .AllowAnyHeader()
                    .AllowAnyMethod()
                    .AllowCredentials()
                );
        });
```

In the front-end I use `angularjs`. The method looks like this:

```
this.addFile = function (file) {
            return $http.post(fileApi, file);
        };
```

I debuged it on the front and it looks alright, except the string with the byte array is so big it hangs my browser sometimes. So As I mentioned, it works for smaller files, only occurs for the bigger ones. It obviously has to do something with the weight of the file.

I tried to debug back-end, but it doesnt even reach the controller, so there is no way. Any ideas? Thanks a lot!

Edit:

My web.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="10000000" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="10000000" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
    <handlers>
      <add name="httpPlatformHandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="httpPlatformHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <httpPlatform processPath="%DNX_PATH%" arguments="%DNX_ARGS%" stdoutLogEnabled="false" startupTimeLimit="3600" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Does the error occur with other web-servers such as Kestrel or WebListener?

Comment: Have you tried to look into solving the CORS issue instead? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31942037/how-to-enable-cors-in-asp-net-5

Comment: @diemaus I'm doing it on Kestrel right now, I haven't try it on other servers. Guo Hong Lim It is not an issue, I set it up right in Startup.cs class. Besides, it works with smaller files just right

Comment: @RichardRahl any update on this, I'm interested in knowing if this has been solved.

Comment: As it's a .NET Core issue, which is in early developement I managed to go across CORS problem, but as I thought it was a red herring. I have put this on hold, because this may be an MVC bug, I will see in a couple of weeks if anything changed.

Answer (score 0):

add this to your `Web.Config`, it will allow you to upload the content up to 10MB. (10000000 = 10 MB)

```
<system.web>
  <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="10000000" />
</system.web>

<system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="10000000" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
</system.webServer>
```

Hope this help

Comment: Unfortunetaly the error still occurs, I will post my web.config to the question right now. Thanks for answer!

Answer (score 0):

you must using chunk approach to do that or use stream array

[check this link](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1180464/Large-JSON-Array-Streaming-in-ASP-NET-Web-API)