# EnableCors attribute not adding Access-Control-Allow-Origin to API responses

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, api

**The problem:**

For some reason, when enabling CORS, the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header is not included in the response.

**The error:**

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://.../api/endpoints/some-path' from
> origin 'https://some.site.com' has been blocked by CORS policy:
> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource.

**Configuration (.NET MVC 5)**

*web.config* headers:

```
<system.webServer>
  <httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true"/>
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, OPTIONS" />
    </customHeaders>
  </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```

Web API config:

```
config.EnableCors();
```

API endpoint:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/endpoints")]
[EnableCors(origins: "https://some.site.com", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
public class MyApiController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("some-path")]
    [EnableCors(origins: "https://some.site.com", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
    public ResponseModel GetSomeResponse(DataModel model) { ... }
}
```

*global.asax.cs*

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
}
```

The only way I can get successfully get the application to return that header is to explicitly include it as a custom header in the **web.config**:

```
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="https://some.site.com" />
```

Comment: check if this might be useful https://www.hexacta.com/How-to-enable-CORS-on-your-Web-API

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27218420/2004122

Comment: This worked for me...   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40043097/cors-in-net-core/40286658#40286658

Answer (score 0):

Add same method with `HttpOptions` header and same route name. Browser will send preflight request to your controller. Which means `Options` method will be triggered to access header informations of the server.

```
[HttpOptions]
[Route("some-path")]
[EnableCors(origins: "https://some.site.com", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
public ResponseModel GetSomeResponse(DataModel model) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

From: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api

Confirm that the Access-Control-Request-Method and Access-Control-Request-Headers headers are sent with the request and that OPTIONS headers reach the app through IIS.

To configure IIS to allow an ASP.NET app to receive and handle OPTION requests, add the following configuration to the app's web.config file in the <system.webServer> section:

```
<system.webServer>
  <handlers>
    <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
    <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
    <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
  </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

The removal of OPTIONSVerbHandler prevents IIS from handling OPTIONS requests. The replacement of ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0 allows OPTIONS requests to reach the app because the default module registration only allows GET, HEAD, POST, and DEBUG requests with extensionless URLs.

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me. Handling pre-flight request and cors
Web.config

```
<system.webServer>   
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
```

Global.asax.cs

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
            {
                //These headers are handling the "pre-flight" OPTIONS call sent by the browser
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "*"); // For All HttpVerb
                //HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE");
                //HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Authorization, Content-Type, Accept");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*");
                //HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow‌​-Credentials", "true");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "600");//1728000
                HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusCode = 204;

                HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
            }
        }
```

WebApiConfig.cs

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    config.EnableCors();
    ....
}
```

Add Attribuites in your controller

```
[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
```

Answer (score 0):

Always try to keep your code *simple* and *clear* if possible.

Actually, **There's no need to change** the *web.config*, *controllers* or *global.asax.cs*. So clean them and **Just use the following configuration** inside `Configure` method in *Startup.cs* file :

```
app.UseExceptionHandler(builder =>
{
    builder.Run(
    async context =>
    {
        context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
        context.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

        var error = context.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>();
        if (error != null)
        {
            context.Response.AddApplicationError(error.Error.Message);
            await context.Response.WriteAsync(error.Error.Message).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
    });
});
```

Where `ResponseExtensions` is defined as extension with the following details:

```
public static class ResponseExtensions
{
    public static void AddApplicationError(this HttpResponse response, string message)
    {
        response.Headers.Add("Application-Error", message);
        // CORS
        response.Headers.Add("access-control-expose-headers", "Application-Error");
    }
}
```

This is working fine in my fully API-based Asp.net project.

Answer (score -1):

Set CORS globally for all the controllers. Inside `WebApiConfig` class, Create the instance of EnableCorsAttribute and use in EnableCors method as:

```
var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("https://some.site.com", "*", "*");
config.EnableCors(cors);
```

Comment: This works, but has the same effect as adding it in the web.config. I would like to have more fine-grained control over CORS policy on a per-API or endpoint basis and not set it as the same value for all requests.

Comment: If you want to implement CORS as per-API basis then apply this attribute on method attribute instead of controller level: `[EnableCors(origins: "https://some.site.com", headers: "*", methods: "*")]`

Comment: Yes, that's mentioned in the original post. Adding the attribute does not result in an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header being added to the response.

Comment: But in the original post, you have applied it controller level. Remove from controller and apply only on method.

Comment: You're right, I've edited it to make it clear I've tried both approaches. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Try with http instead of https

Comment: No dice with either http or https.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218936/discussion-between-imran-and-ianpoley).

Answer (score -1):

Globally Enable CORS
The method described can also be used to enable CORS across the API without annotating each controller as per below in WebApiConfig

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    var corsAttr = new EnableCorsAttribute("http://example.com", "*", "*");
    config.EnableCors(corsAttr);
}
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to the StackOverflow. If you can provide more detail about the code, it would be a better answer, here is a tip: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: You are correct, but that does not solve my issue. I need to be able to set different `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` on a per-endpoint basis.

Answer (score -1):

I followed the same steps that are shared by Shaun in below post where we can enable CORS at method level. It works fine for me.
Could you please try at your end?

[Asp.Net WebApi2 Enable CORS not working with AspNet.WebApi.Cors 5.2.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29024313/asp-net-webapi2-enable-cors-not-working-with-aspnet-webapi-cors-5-2-3)