# How can I use CORS for ASP.Net Core

Tags: asp.net, .net, cors

I want to build an ASP.NET Service thats called from another server but it does not allow me to access the Service.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to enable CORS in ASP.NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31942037/how-to-enable-cors-in-asp-net-core)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All you need is to insert this code in your startup.cs:

`app.UseCors(builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod());`

just keep in mind to use it above:

`app.UseMvc()`

Have fun!

Answer (score 3):

You should take a look at [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors) to see all the available options:

- **simple setup**

  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
  {
      services.AddCors();
  }
- **setup with middleware**

  ```
  public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
  {
      // Shows UseCors with CorsPolicyBuilder.
      app.UseCors(options => options.WithOrigins("http://example.com").AllowAnyMethod());

      // other code may come here
  }
  ```
- **CORS in MVC project**

**Action level**

```
[EnableCors("AllowSpecificOrigin")]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [EnableCors("AllowSpecificOrigin")]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

**Controller level**

```
[EnableCors("AllowSpecificOrigin")]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
}
```

and much options like allowed origins, allowed HTTP methods, exposed response headers, how to handle credentials.

Try setting up yourself and come here with a *specific* problem if you encounter one.

Answer (score 2):

Please make sure to install the [nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors/)

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors
```

Configure the `startup.cs` similar to the following:

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        //...
    }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        //...
        //Register Cors policy
        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
                builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowCredentials());
        });
        services.AddMvc();
        //...

    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        //...
        app.UseCors("CorsPolicy"); //Make sure the policy name matches with the provided above
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors now deprecated

Answer (score 0):

**You can configure CORS in Startup class  in the ConfigureServices method** `

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{  
      services.AddCors(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
            builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .AllowAnyHeader()
            .AllowCredentials());
    });
}
```

**apply it to every request**

```
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
app.UseCors("MyPolicy");
}
```

**you can apply on Controller or Method Also e.g add attribute**

```
[EnableCors("MyPolicy")]
```