# IdentityServer4 + MVC client in Docker

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, authentication, identityserver4, openid-connect

I want to deploy IdentityServer4 and MVC client in Docker. As reverse proxy I use NGINX. But my containers don't have access to the external network. (red lines on the picture below)
[image]

My MVC client application requests discovery document over the internal network and receives internal URI's. But they are used by client-side code in a browser. FQDN can be an IP address with a port or regular domain name. What needs to be done to fix my problem?
I found [similar question](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/7803). There was recommended to use the same DNS name and resolve it inside the docker-compose network to IdentityServer4 container. But what to do in the case of IP address?
And same problems with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43923352/4707524).
I even thought about migrating to oidc-client.js. But it will take too much time.

**MVC client:**

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
            })
            .AddCookie("Cookies")
            .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
            {
                options.Authority = "http://fqdn/idsrv";
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;

                options.ClientId = "mvc";
                options.SaveTokens = true;
            });
```

****IdentityServer4**:**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

        var builder = services.AddIdentityServer(o => {

        })
            .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Config.GetIdentityResources())
            .AddInMemoryApiResources(Config.GetApis())
            .AddInMemoryClients(Config.GetClients())
            .AddTestUsers(Config.GetUsers());

        builder.AddDeveloperSigningCredential();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.UsePathBase("/idsrv");
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();

        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseIdentityServer();

        app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
    }
```

**docker-compose:**

```
version: "3.9"
services: 
mvcclient:
    build: 
        context: .
        dockerfile: \MvcClient\Dockerfile 
identityserver:
    build: 
        context: .
        dockerfile: \IdentityServer\Dockerfile
proxy:
    image: nginx
    ports:
        - "80:80"
```

**NGINX:**

```
location ~* ^/idsrv {
        proxy_pass http://identityserver;
    }
location ~* ^/mvcclient {
        proxy_pass http://mvcclient;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the best solution but it takes place.

**MVC client:**

```
.AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
    {
        options.Authority = "http://{public_fqdn}/idsrv";
        options.MetadataAddress = "http://{idsrv_container_name}/.well-known/openid-configuration";
        options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidIssuer = "http://{public_fqdn}/idsrv";

        options.Events.OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = context =>
        {
            // Intercept the redirection so the browser navigates to the right URL in your host
            context.ProtocolMessage.IssuerAddress = "http://{public_fqdn}/idsrv/connect/authorize";
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        };

        options.Events.OnRedirectToIdentityProviderForSignOut = context =>
        {
            // Intercept the redirection so the browser navigates to the right URL in your host
            context.ProtocolMessage.IssuerAddress = "http://{public_fqdn}/idsrv/connect/endsession";
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        };

        options.ClientId = "mvc";
    })
```