# Authorize Attribute to handle valid user in Docker

Tags: docker, .net-core, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

I am running my .net core 5 application, namely `Authentication Server` and `API Gateway`, in Docker in Linux container. And controller class in the `API GateWay` contains an `[Authorize]` attributes to validate the user. Despite the user is valid (eg register and log in successfully), API Gate is unable allow the user to access the API. And here a part of my log that is complaining:

```
Failed to validate the token.Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenSignatureKeyNotFoundException: IDX10501: Signature validation failed. Unable to match key:
kid: '6B7ACC520305BFDB4F7252DAEB2177CC091FAAE1'.
Exceptions caught:''.
```

Am I right to say that, is it due to the cookies generated by Identity Service 4; `idsrv.session` and `.netcore related cookies` failed to be shared.

This is because based on my observation when my micro-services are running in IIS. The Authentication Server, shall generates two mentioned cookies when user logs in successfully. And the mentioned cookies are "shared" among the rest of the micro-services, partly because they are in the same localhost but different port number.

When my application are migrated to Docker; the Authentication Server is able to generate the related cookies, the rest of the contains failed to get the cookies.

And as the result, which I'm guessing, that is the result that API Gateway is unable to authorise a valid user.

Hence, I am wondering is my understanding of Authorization is correct and how should I fix the issue with a valid user.

Comment: This should help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43911536/how-can-i-use-identityserver4-from-inside-and-outside-a-docker-machine

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/58877655/3312570
The error code `IDX10501` points to incorrect bearer token middleware.

Try adding cookies. Use the below code. My guess, it won't help.

`services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddCookie();`