# Getting error while calling a remote web API

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, asp.net-web-api

I am working website and hitting a third party api but getting an error
 `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource`

Ajax:

```
var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT');
    headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
    headers.append('content-type', 'application/json');
    headers.append('AuthToken', '2948f47085e9d8ecd95bd21ebe024a01516105f9')
    headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:61030/Test.aspx');
    headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');

    $.ajax({
        crossDomain: true,
        type: "GET",
        url: "https://api.travelcloudpro.eu/v1/cache/flyfrom?origin=DEL&pointOfSale=US",
        //headers: { '[{"key":"AuthToken","value":"2948f47085e9d8ecd95bd21ebe024a01516105f9","description":""}]': 'some value' },
        //  header: { 'AuthToken': '2948f47085e9d8ecd95bd21ebe024a01516105f9' },
        header:headers,
        dataType: "json",
        data:{},
        success: function (data) {
            debugger;
            var flightresponse = data;

            //alert($("#city").val());
        }
    });
```

While calling from postman it works fine.

[image]

I don't know what is missing, TIA.

if i change datatype json to jsonp then getting this error :- [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ytDuE.png)

Comment: You're using GET in postman...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does my JavaScript get a "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource" error when Postman does not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/why-does-my-javascript-get-a-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource—when trying to get data from a REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43871637/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource-whe)

Comment: Read [ask] and share your research. Adding random response headers as request headers isn't going to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

i guess as you mentioned "third party api" you are sending request to a server with different ip address (or port number) which makes a CORS error(Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) in most browsers like firefox and chrome.

[***+here you can read more about why it happens.+***](https://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/05/25/cross-domain-ajax-with-cross-origin-resource-sharing/)

you need to add a CORS Filter which is discussed [***+here+***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31942037/how-to-enable-cors-in-asp-net-core).

I`m not a .net programmer but i hope it could help.

Comment: i m not getting you, do i need to modify my ajax call?

Comment: no it must be fixed from the server side . i`m sorry i`m not familiar with ASP.net so please refer to the page i linked for you.