# Asp.net Core and Angular 7 Cors

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, file-upload

Why do im receving the `Cors Error`

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:5000/api/upload' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

As far as i understand. The cors is enabled in my startup class in my `asp.net core web api`

And here is my code

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddCors();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseCors(x => x.AllowAnyOrigin()
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .AllowAnyHeader());

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseMvc();
}
```

And this is my Angular 7 Code

The html for `fileupload`

```
<form [formGroup]="formGroup" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <div class="form-group">
      <input type="file" name="image"  />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
      <button class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

And this is the `fileupload.component.ts`

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-fileupload',
  templateUrl: './fileupload.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./fileupload.component.css']
})
export class FileuploadComponent implements OnInit {
  fileData: File = null;
  formGroup = new FormGroup({
    one: new FormControl
  });
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  fileProgress(fileInput: any) {
    this.fileData = <File>fileInput.target.files[0];
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  onSubmit() {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', this.fileData);
    this.http.post('http://localhost:5000/api/upload', formData)
    .subscribe(res => {
      console.log(res);
      alert('SUCCESS !!');
    })

    console.log('Called');
  }

}
```

Actually im following this tutorial:

```
https://www.tutsmake.com/new-angular-7-upload-file-image-example/
```

And im in the part where i am checking the file upload api with the help of the Angular 7. I tested the API using postman and it worked correctly with the code in the api so far

[image]

And below is the Upload controller code

```
[Produces("application/json")]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class UploadController : Controller
    {
        // GET: /<controller>/
        public IActionResult Index()
        {

            try
            {
                var file = Request.Form.Files[0];
                Console.WriteLine();

                return null;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
                throw ex;
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm also receving an error

```
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.' on

var file = Request.Form.Files[0];
```

is this because of the Angular 7 is not sending data?

Thank you so much.

Comment: Would you like to upload a file? If so, it should be a post and not a get. Usually you should check if there are any files uploaded, but also you should handle if there is more than one file in the list. There is a simple example in the mircosoft docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: For information about using cors in ASP.NET Core: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31942037/how-to-enable-cors-in-asp-net-core

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:5000/api/upload' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Actually, I doubt whether you forgot to **restart the ASP.NET Core Server after you configure the `CORS`**.

Assuming you're using the default template, your existing code works fine for me. 
If you still cannot make it, you could paste the complete code of your `Startup` class.

> I'm also receving an error
>
> ```
> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.' on
>
> var file = Request.Form.Files[0];
> ```
>
> is this because of the Angular 7 is not sending data?

Yes. That's because **you haven't binded an event handler to set the `fileData` property when selecting a file**.

To fix it, create a method of **`onFileChange(event)`**:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-fileupload',
  templateUrl: './fileupload.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./fileupload.component.css']
})
export class FileuploadComponent implements OnInit {

  // ...

  onFileChange(event){
    this.fileData = <File> event.target.files[0];
  }

  // ...
}
```

and change your template as below:

```
<form [formGroup]="formGroup" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <div class="form-group">
      <input type="file" name="image" (change)="onFileChange($event)"  />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
      <button class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

---

As a side note, don't return a `null` as an `IActionResult` within your action method. It will result in an unhandled exception:

```
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        try
        {
            var file = Request.Form.Files[0];
            Console.WriteLine();

            return null;             ////////// don't return null
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // ...
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for very complete answer. This works for me.