# Access to API Method from origin has been blocked by CORS policy

Tags: angular, api, .net-core, cors, cross-origin-read-blocking

I'm using .Net Core to build API and Angular Web application to consume those APIs. Both are hosted locally with different ports.

**.Net Core API:** http://localhost:5000

**Angular Web App:** http://localhost:4444

Here are my Service methods in Angular

```
export class AdvertisementService {
  // Define API 
  apiURL = environment.apiUrl;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  // Configure HTTP Options
  httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    })
  }

  // HttpClient API get() method => Fetch Advertisement List.
  getAdvertisements(): Observable<Advertisement[]> {
    return this.http.get<Advertisement>(this.apiURL + '/Advertisements')
                    .pipe(retry(1),catchError(this.handleError))
  }

  // HttpClient API post() method => Create Advertisement
  createAdvertisement(advertisement): Observable<Advertisement> {
    return this.http.post<Advertisement>(this.apiURL + '/Advertisements', JSON.stringify(advertisement), this.httpOptions)
    .pipe(retry(1),catchError(this.handleError))
  }  

  private handleError(error: any): Promise<any> {
    console.error('An error occurred', error); // for demo purposes only
    return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
  }
}
```

When I call API methods via Angular App it is throwing following error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
>   'http://localhost:5000/api/Advertisements' from origin
>   'http://localhost:4444' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request
>   header field content-type is not allowed by
>   Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

I added CORS in my .Net Core as below in **ConfigureServices** method:

```
 services.AddCors(options =>
 {
     options.AddPolicy(MyAllowSpecificOrigins,
     builder =>
     {
         builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4444");
     });
 });
```

Comment: you need to setup cors on your .NET Api https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31942037/how-to-enable-cors-in-asp-net-core

Comment: I did the same thing as mentioned in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31942037/how-to-enable-cors-in-asp-net-core)  but same error

Answer (score 1):

add `services.AddCors();` in ConfigureServices Method and `app.UseCors(x => x.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod());` in Configure method at startup.cs

Answer (score 0):

Enable CORS in WebApi.config:

```
var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");
config.EnableCors(cors);
```

Comment: I'm using .Net Core API application

Answer (score 0):

As per solution mentioned in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31942037/how-to-enable-cors-in-asp-net-core), following is working for me.

```
readonly string MyAllowSpecificOrigins = "_myAllowSpecificOrigins";

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{ 
    services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy(MyAllowSpecificOrigins, builder =>
    {
        builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
               .AllowAnyMethod()
               .AllowAnyHeader();
    }));
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins);
}
```