# ASP.NET Core CORS WebAPI: persist no Access-Control-Allow-Origin header

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi

I deployed the application on the production server of my web.api and I get the following error in the browser console (**seems solved**):

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
>   'https://ebbtelemetrywebapi.azurewebsites.net/api//events' from origin
>   'https://ebbwatelem.azurewebsites.net' has been blocked by CORS
>   policy: No     'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the
>   requested resource.

Before this error I have the following (**seems solved**):

> POST https://localhost:44340/api/events 500

The header of the called function is the following :

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<CosmosDBEvents>> GetAsync([FromBody]EventsGetTwoParamsDto dto)
```

The DTO declaration is the following :

```
public class EventsGetTwoParamsDto
{
    public string DeviceIdorId { get; set; }
    public string Action2 { get; set; }
}
```

and the ajax call is the following :

```
 $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url: ENV.apiUrl+'/events',
        data: JSON.stringify({DeviceIdorId: ENV.deviceId, Action2 : "Pagina5"}),
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
        success: function(data){
            console.log("RISPOSTA", data);
        }
    });
```

The Startup.cs/ConfigurationServices method contains the lines:

```
 services.AddCors(); // Make sure you call this previous to AddMvc
 services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
```

and thr Startup.cs/Configure method contains :

```
   app.UseCors(         
      options=> options.AllowAnyOrigin()
                       .AllowAnyHeader()
                       .AllowAnyMethod()
                       .AllowCredentials());
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.
Simone

---

All the issues is related to the second one solved changing the declaration of the method in the controller as shown below :

```
[HttpPost]
public async 
Task<IEnumerable<CosmosDBTelemetry>>GetAsync(TelemetriesTwoParamsDto dto)
```

Thanks to all,
Simone

Comment: In Startup.cs class ConfigureServices() Add below code            `services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("AllowAllOrigins",
                builder1 =>
                {
                    builder1
                    .AllowAnyOrigin()
                    .AllowAnyHeader()
                    .AllowAnyMethod()
                    .AllowCredentials();
                });
            });`
In the same class Configure method you have to add `app.UseCors("AllowAllOrigins")`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to enable CORS in ASP.NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31942037/how-to-enable-cors-in-asp-net-core)

Comment: I can see that your web app is hosted on azure. In azure there is a setting to enable cors. [Azure CORS Configuration](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/5bd37aa7-eed7-4ddd-a560-c36a09e1674d/how-can-i-enable-the-cors-on-my-app-hosted-on-azure-portal?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview)

Comment: See Azure storage cors configuration: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/cross-origin-resource-sharing--cors--support-for-the-azure-storage-services

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be misplacing the code.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("AllowAnyOrigin",
                builder => builder
                .AllowAnyOrigin()
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader());
        });

        // other code           
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    app.UseCors("AllowAnyOrigin");

    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding the default policy to `ConfigureServices` method:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddCors(options =>
    {
        options.AddDefaultPolicy(builder =>
        {
            builder.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader();
        });
    }

    // (...)
}
```

See ASP.NET Core [CORS documentation section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-2.2#enable-cors-with-attributes) for reference.

You can also try adding `"AllowedHosts": "*"` to `appsettings.json` file.

Comment: ok. I solved the issue related to Cors. Now I still get the other error.

Comment: doesn't work net.core50 webapi :(