# .NET Core Windows authentication - React vs Postman

Tags: reactjs, .net-core, cors, fetch

I have this problem that driving me nuts ... I got backend API, that has CORS enabled and Windows Authentication, looks like this

launchSettings.json:

```
"iisSettings": {
   "windowsAuthentication": true,
   "anonymousAuthentication": false,
   ....
}
```

Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddCors();
    services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_3_0);
}
```

And

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
     if (env.IsDevelopment())
     {
         app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
     }

     app.UseRouting();
     app.UseAuthentication();
     app.UseAuthorization();

     app.UseCors(builder => builder
        .AllowAnyOrigin()
        .AllowAnyHeader()
        .AllowAnyMethod());

     app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
     {
         endpoints.MapControllers();
      });
}
```

TokenController.cs

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class TokenController : ControllerBase
{
    private TokenService userService;
    IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor;

    public TokenController(TokenService _userService, 
                           IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor)
    {
        userService = _userService;
        httpContextAccessor = _httpContextAccessor;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates token for domain signed user of Unicredit group
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>Authenticate</returns>
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("")]
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(string), 200)]
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(string), 400)]
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(string), 404)]
    [Produces("application/json")]
    public IActionResult Authenticate()
    {
        string username = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;
        ... further reading from AD and making JWT token 
    }
```

React - Authenticate.js  (doing simple fetch)

```
fetch(`${AuthenticationEndpoint}/`)
     .then(response => response.json())
     .then(data => this.onSetResult(data));
```

So when I call my API with use of `Boomerang` (Postman alike) and just doing simple `GET` for `https://localhost:{port}/Token/`, I get `status 200` and my JWT Token back, but once I do fetch from my React application I keep getting error:

`Access to fetch at 'https://localhost:44351/Token/' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy`

I understand not Boomerang nor Postman are restricted by policy and that's reason why they can pass to my API, but how can I let my application access my API?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31942037/how-to-enable-cors-in-asp-net-core  This post has some good ideas for troubleshooting your issue

Comment: @Grax32 thank you, I checked that question before posting a question, but it wasn't much of a use in fixing the problem

Comment: What CORS header do you see if you use the browser tools to view it?

Comment: @Grax32 I figured it out ...

Comment: allow cors on controller, jeepers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**FIXED IT**

Because I had

```
"iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": true,
    "anonymousAuthentication": false,
```

My cors were expecting username, which I do need in order to query AD and make JWT token

I had to change fetch, and set `credentials` to `include` and change `useCors` in Startup.cs

```
fetch(`${AuthenticationEndpoint}/Authenticate`, {
            credentials: "include",
            method: "GET",
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        }).then((response) => {
            response.json().then(data => {
                this.onSetResult(data);
            })
 });
```

And CORS on backend were set like this:

```
 app.UseCors(builder => builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:3000")
                               .AllowAnyMethod()
                               .AllowAnyHeader()
                               .AllowCredentials());
```