# Api call gives 204 from application

Tags: reactjs, api, http-status-code-204

I have deployed my react app and .net core api on server. .net core api call works fine when I checked from browser. But when I invoke it from react app it gives 204 no-content. Everything works fine in local.

I have enabled CORS like this

```
options.AddPolicy(MyAllowSpecificOrigins,
                builder =>
                {
                    builder.WithOrigins("http://serverip:5000",
                            "http://serverip:3000"
}
```

api call---

```
[HttpGet]
    [Route("path/{id}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<List<myData>>> GetByType(byte id)
    {

      if (IsUserAuthenticated())
            return await _myRepo.GetMyData(id);
        else
            return null;
    }
```

react call-----

```
      axios.get('http://ip:5000/api/value1/value2/' + param1, { 
      withCredentials: true })
```

Appreciate any help !

Comment: Please provide more information. We need to see the controller and action code, plus the react call. Could be the way you call your api, the server can't make a response with content.

Comment: I have added those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end,it was a silly mistake from my end. I had hardcoded localhost url somewhere in the flow and that was causing CORS issue when accessing from server. Appreciate all the help !

Answer (score 1):

Your api route is

```
[Route("path/{id}")]
```

you should change

```
axios.get('http://ip:5000/api/value1/value2/' + param1, { 
      withCredentials: true })
```

to

```
axios.get('http://ip:5000/api/path/' + param1, { 
      withCredentials: true })
```

Comment: Thanks ! When i tried to change the actual names and parameters that changed a bit. However the url works fine and returns data. Only concern is it does not return anything when called from application.

Comment: I think its CORS issue. check this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/31942128/4855817

Comment: I'll check. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Try to change the code to

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("path/{id}")]
public async Task<ActionResult<List<myData>>> GetByType(byte id)
{

  if (IsUserAuthenticated())
        return await _myRepo.GetMyData(id);
    else {
        HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 401;
        return null;
     }
}
```

This will make sure that the NoContent 204 result is not just the null part of the code.

If you get the unauthorized response, then you need to figure out your security.

By the way, you could use a filter for authorization or an attribute instead of writing it on every action.