# .Net Core 3.1 API Action method with [HTTPPost] returns 405 with incorrect Response Header Allow

Tags: c#, .net-core

I searched around and couldn't find a way to fix my issue.
I have actions method below:

PostAction method with [Route("api/Deployments")]
[image: PostAction method with [Route("api/Deployments")]]
Client Post Request
[image: Client post request]

**Why is the Response Header Allow does have POST?**

[image: inspect]

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You are running to a CORS issue. You need to allow AJAX requests from a different domain. For example:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("MyPolicy", builder =>
  {
    builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
           .AllowAnyMethod()
           .AllowAnyHeader();
  }));

  // ...
}
```

And then apply this policy to controllers or actions as needed:

```
[EnableCors("MyPolicy")]
```

See [How to enable CORS in ASP.NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31942037/how-to-enable-cors-in-asp-net-core) and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-3.1 for more details and examples.

Generally, and as a security measure, it is not a good practice to allow requests from all domains (*).

Comment: Hi, I have follow your suggestion and setup CORS and I'm getting 405 Error, it doesn't look like CORS issue, because no complain about origin.