# URL has been blocked by CORS policy

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm getting below error on calling API from  ASP.Net MVC in angular version 1

[image]
Error:
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'URL 1' from origin 'URL 2' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.

I use below code in WebApiConfig:

```
     var corsAttr = new EnableCorsAttribute("*","*","*");
                config.EnableCors(corsAttr);
```

After that I tried to use below code :

```
var corsAttr = new EnableCorsAttribute("*","Content-Type", "GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS");
            config.EnableCors(corsAttr);
```

and:

```
var corsAttr = new EnableCorsAttribute("https://rushpeik.ir","Content-Type", "GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS");
            config.EnableCors(corsAttr);
```

But the problem remains

Comment: What is the version of ASP.Net MVC?

Comment: dot net framework 4.5.1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to enable CORS in ASP.NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31942037/how-to-enable-cors-in-asp-net-core)

Comment: No, It just work for ASP.net .Core

Comment: A common mistake people seem to make in this situation is to be trying to apply CORS settings in the wrong project - so, to be clear, the code you're showing is code you've added to the *API* project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution:

At the first have to use below code in WebApiConfig

```
     var corsAttr = new EnableCorsAttribute("*","*","*");
                config.EnableCors(corsAttr);
```

After that add below code to web.config

```
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

We have to allow all custom headers in "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" like below line:

```
 <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type,Token,Username" />
```

It worked for me :)

Answer (score 2):

Here you need to add this in your Configure() method in your startup.cs

```
app.UseCors(builder => builder.WithOrigins("*")
                               .AllowAnyMethod()
                               .AllowAnyHeader());
```

Answer (score 2):

Add this above your Api Class

```
[EnableCors(origins: "https://rushpeik.ir", headers: "*", methods: "*")] 
public class YourController : ApiController
{
        // Whatever
}
```