# Can not get data from api in my angular 11 project

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core-webapi

I develop a web API using .NET Core web API and then try to get data from it to my Angular11.

these are the codes
shared.service.ts

```
   import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
   import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
   import { observable, Observable } from 'rxjs';

   @Injectable({
      providedIn: 'root'
   })
  export class SharedService {
  readonly APIUrl = "http://localhost:5000/api";
  readonly PhotoUrl = "http://localhost:5000/photos";

   constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
   getSecList(): Observable<any[]> {
   return this.http.get<any>(this.APIUrl + '/section');
    }}
```

show-sec.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { SharedService } from './../../shared.service';

@Component({
selector: 'app-show-sec',
templateUrl: './show-sec.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./show-sec.component.css']
})
export class ShowSecComponent implements OnInit {

constructor(private service: SharedService) { }
SectionList: any = [];

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.refreshSecList();
}
refreshSecList() {
  this.service.getSecList().subscribe(data => {
    this.SectionList = data;
    console.log(this.SectionList);

  });
 }

}
```

but I can not get  data from api it shows following error in console.
[image]
how to fix this.

Comment: It's look like a server-side problem ...it happens to me when i run angular on  `localhost:4200` while server on `localhost:5000`... By default, asp.net will not respond for foreign request ... You have to configure a CORS policy at server side application to allow your angular URL as acceptable requites [try to look at this answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31942037/how-to-enable-cors-in-asp-net-cor)

Comment: Did you try to access to the endpoint trough Postman or directly using the browser??