# CORS blocks request even though I explicitly enabled the origin i am requesting from

Tags: c#, api, cors

I have a Website (running angular) with a .net backend. I am experiencing an issue where I can make POST and GET requests successfully from domain https://example.net to domain https://example.net. However the moment I try to make a PUT request, it fails claiming that:

> "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."

In debugging, I have verified that the header is present on GET and POST requests.

In My Backend:
Startup.cs:

```
app.UseCors(c => {
    c.AllowAnyHeader();
    c.AllowAnyMethod();
    c.WithOrigins("https://example.net", "https://www.example.net");
});
```

The Controller:

```
[ApiController]
public class TestController : BaseController { //which derives from ControllerBase

[HttpPut]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public async Task<IActionResult> TestMethod([FromBody] RequestData requestData) {
    //...
}
//...
```

As far as I can tell, it should be working as intended.

*Note:*
I have also tried `c.AllowAnyOrigin()`

Comment: Have you called `app.UseMvc()` before or after `app.UseCors()`? Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31942037/how-to-enable-cors-in-asp-net-core

Comment: we don't call that at all @wil

Comment: You should provide `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin` in your front-end and send in each requests

Comment: Have you tried with httppost ? Is that working ?

Comment: Have you tried this: [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31942037/how-to-enable-cors-in-asp-net-core)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource—when trying to get data from a REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43871637/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource-whe)

Comment: @dotnetstep httppost calls work as described in the question. that doesn't help either

Comment: @PancakeAlchemist that doesn't help either

Comment: @ian that talks about ways to get around the issue but not actually solve the issue

Comment: Have you already tryed to add a new police to your CORS and then decorate your method with EnableCors attribute?

Comment: @osman-rahimi that doesn't seem to be working

Comment: @augusto-ferbonink That seems to be making things worse. as of making that adjustment GET and POST requests don't work anymore

Comment: @DonutMaster96 can you share an git repository with full code? Don't need front end, I'll debug with postman

Comment: @augusto-ferbonink you can do that here: https://github.com/DonutMaster96/tempApi