# How can I solve the CORS error in this C# code?

Tags: c#, reactjs, .net, cors

I have CORS error in my .NETCore+React app. To solve that I've decided to add some configurations in my backend.

```
public Program(IConfiguration configuration)
{
    Configuration = configuration;
}

public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddCors(options =>
    {
        options.AddDefaultPolicy(builder => {
            builder.WithOrigins("http://127.0.0.1:3000/");
        });
    });
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseCors(x=> x
        .AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod().SetIsOriginAllowed(origin=>true).AllowCredentials()
    );
}
```

I wrote it on my Program.cs file. But i still have CORS error. Where did i go wrong?
PS: I am using .NET 2.1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to enable CORS in ASP.NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31942037/how-to-enable-cors-in-asp-net-core)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved my issue with CORS

In ConfigureService method I used the below snippet to allow all origins

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddCors(options=>{
                options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",HostBuilder=>HostBuilder.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod());
            });
           }
```

In configure method just use

```
 app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the Any-Methods in your builder

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddCors(options =>
    {
        options.AddDefaultPolicy(builder => {
            builder.AllowAnyHeader()
                   .AllowAnyMethod()
                   .AllowCredentials()
                   .WithOrigins("http://127.0.0.1:3000/");
        });
    });
}
```

In your `Configure` method you now only need to write

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    ...
    app.UseCors();
    ...
}
```

Keep in mind, this only allows cross origin requests from the specified origin, in this case `http://127.0.0.1:3000`, if you want to allow requests from anywhere, you can replace `.WithOrigins(...)` with `.AllowAnyOrigin()`

---

In case you don't want to override the default policy, you can also add a name

```
options.AddDefaultPolicy("MyPolicy", builder => {
    builder.AllowAnyHeader()
         .AllowAnyMethod()
         .AllowCredentials()
         .WithOrigins("http://127.0.0.1:3000/");
});
```

but now you would need to write

```
app.UseCors("MyPolicy");
```

You can apply this policy to your controller/actions with

```
[EnableCors("MyPolicy")]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can

- add `"proxy": "http://serverip:port"` into `package.json`file of react app
- use nginx proxy your react app api
- add code to `Startup.cs` of webapi

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddCors(options => {
        options.AddPolicy("any", builder =>
        {
            builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .AllowAnyHeader()
            .AllowCredentials();
        });
    });
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseCors("any");
}
```

I recommend the first method