# How to configure CORS settings properly for proxying website

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, cors

My application `GET`s the pages from a website and displays them in a localhost domain. but on specific websites (like habr) I receive a message like so:
[image: devtools console]

the code which does all the stuff:

```cs
app.Run(async (context) =>
{
    var url = context.Request.GetDisplayUrl()
        .Replace(@"https://localhost:5001", "");
    var request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(@"https://habr.com" + url);
    var responce = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse();
    var resStream = responce.GetResponseStream();
    var reader = new StreamReader(resStream);
    await context.Response.WriteAsync(await reader.ReadToEndAsync());
});
```

and the CORS:

```cs
app.UseCors(builder =>
{
    builder.DisallowCredentials();
    builder.AllowAnyHeader();
    builder.AllowAnyMethod();
    builder.AllowAnyOrigin();
});
```

I've tried without `DisallowCredentials`, but it didn't help. Tried to proxy StackOverflow, and it worked fine.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31942037/how-to-enable-cors-in-asp-net-core) answer your question?

Comment: no, it doesn't. As you can see, i tried setting CORS to allow everything.

Comment: Are you calling `app.UseCors` before or after `app.UseMvc`?

Comment: i'm not using MVC. I just need to proxy a website via my localhost domain. Or MVC is required here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error is telling you that your app, `https://localhost:5001`, cannot access the proxied target destination, `...marketing/?page`. This is **not** a problem that can be solved by setting your own CORS policy: it's the target's CORS policy that is restricting the access.

In other words, your `localhost` app is making an `XMLHttpRequest` to a destination that revokes the connection for violating *their* CORS policy.

Comment: i thought so, but was not sure. Thank you for your answer