# CORS in .NET 6.0 web api

Tags: c#, webapi, .net-6.0

I have a React app calling a .NET 6 Web API using Axios.

In the program.cs file, I have added  builder.Services.AddCors and app.UseCors as below.

But I still get CORS error and 404 preflight.

The method used to works in .NET 5 Web Api.

Is there anything we need to set for .NET 6 Web Api ?

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;
<removed>

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddCors();

// Add services to the container.
<removed>

// App settings
<removed>

<removed>

builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

builder.Services.AddControllers()
    .AddJsonOptions(options =>
    {
        options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new DateTimeConverter());
    });

// AutoMapper
builder.Services.AddAutoMapper(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());

// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();

<removed>

// Firebase
<removed>

var app = builder.Build();
```

The CORS registration is

```
app.UseCors(x => x.AllowAnyHeader()
      .AllowAnyMethod()
      .WithOrigins("https://our-react-site.com"));
```

And the rest of the code

```
// Configure the HTTP request pipeline. 
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI();

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthentication();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

Comment: what do you mean isn't working?

Comment: When we load the React APP in Chrome, we get :
CORS error and 404 preflight.

Comment: You're making the `UseCors` call at the wrong point

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31942037/how-to-enable-cors-in-asp-net-core/53280377#53280377 Issue solved by Allowing OPTIONS verb.

Answer (score 16):

The [CORS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-6.0#enable-cors) explain that UseCors middleware needs to be called in the correct order.

> UseCors must be called in the correct order. For more information, see [Middleware order](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-6.0#middleware-order). For example, UseCors must be called before UseResponseCaching when using UseResponseCaching.

The [Middleware Order](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-6.0#middleware-order) section shows that `UseCors` needs to be called after redirection and routing and before authentication and authorization.

[image]

In your code you'll have to call `UseCors` after `UseHttpsRedirection` and right before `UseAuthentication` :

```
app.UseHttpsRedirection();


app.UseCors(x => x.AllowAnyHeader()
      .AllowAnyMethod()
      .WithOrigins("https://our-react-site.com"));

app.UseAuthentication();
```

The documentation example shows this:

```
var  MyAllowSpecificOrigins = "_myAllowSpecificOrigins";

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(name: MyAllowSpecificOrigins,
                      builder =>
                      {
                          builder.WithOrigins("http://example.com",
                                              "http://www.contoso.com");
                      });
});

// services.AddResponseCaching();

builder.Services.AddControllers();

var app = builder.Build();
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();

app.UseCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins);

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

Another difference is that the doc example creates at least one named policy and uses `UseCors` to apply this policy.

Comment: Thanks. Somehow the code works in local but doesn't work in live (hosted on IIS 10). Is there any setting on server / IIS that might cause this? Web.config file is the same as local.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31942037/how-to-enable-cors-in-asp-net-core/53280377#53280377

Issue solved by allowing OPTIONS Verb

Comment: Order is very important. I had custom extensions to cleanup `Program.cs`. One of those was adding the `UseRouting` middleware before `UseHttpsRedirection` that I was unaware of.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using `UseMiddleware`, `UseCors` must be specified before it e.g.

```
var app = builder.Build();

app.UseCors(policy => policy.AllowAnyHeader()
                            .AllowAnyMethod()
                            .SetIsOriginAllowed(origin => true)
                            .AllowCredentials());

app.UseMiddleware<ApiKeyMiddleware>();
```

Answer (score 0):

added this to my program.cs file in .NET 6.0 web api

```
app.UseCors(options => options.AllowAnyOrigin());
```

Comment: Please expand on your question and explain how it adds to the question and existing answer.

Comment: Please don't use this in production! This will leave your site vulnerable to cross-site request forgery.

Answer (score -1):

You might be blocking the OPTIONS http verb in IIS. Check the "HTTP Verbs" Tab in Request Filtering settings in your IIS. Remove the highlighted option as shown in the image from the link below.

[IIS Request Filtering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6uyNC.png)

Comment: Downvoted, because he literally wrote that this fixed it, several times, before you posted this answer.