# Applying CORS on ASP.NET Core 1.1 not working as expected

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core, cors, cross-domain, same-origin-policy

On ASP.NET Core 1.1.

I included the nuget package `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors" Version="1.1.2`.

`Startup.cs` has CORS code shown below.

These are the issues:

- Issue 1: as per the below code CORS has been configured to allow **only** 'POST' but it allows **ALL** http methods not restricting only to 'POST'
- Issue 2: CORS has been configured only to allow "CustomHeader1", "CustomHeader2" but **NOT** allowing any request headers including valid "CustomHeader1", "CustomHeader2" request headers. If I remove headers altogether in the request then only receiving response.

Code:

```
 public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
 {
     services.AddCors();
 }

 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
 {
     app.UseCors(builder => builder
                                .AllowAnyOrigin()
                                .WithMethods("POST")
                                .WithHeaders("CustomHeader1", "CustomHeader2")
                );
 }
```

What I'm missing to configure CORS only for POST method & to allow only "CustomHeader1", "CustomHeader2" in the request?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this syntax

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
            ....
            services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("AllowAnyOrigin", builder =>
            {
                builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                       .AllowAnyMethod()
                       .AllowAnyHeader();
            }));

             .....
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
            ....

            app.UseRouting();   
            app.UseCors("AllowAnyOrigin");
            //app.UseAuthentication();
            //app.UseAuthorization();
           ....
}
```

only if it works, you can try to add some restrictions.

Comment: @ Serge, this too works but **can't able to restrict** CORS using .WithMethods("POST")
    .WithHeaders("CustomHeader1", "CustomHeader2") what would be the issue?

Comment: @191180rk only if it works, you can try to add some restrictions.

Comment: restriction not considered despite being restriction added. Code added  .AllowAnyOrigin()
    .WithMethods("POST")
    .WithHeaders("CustomHeader1", "CustomHeader2"). With this code, CORS is working for even GET method which it should not.

Comment: @191180rk Get method works always, it doesn' t need CORS. Cors needed for POST mostly. And you are very lucky that it works without restrictions. In the many cases it doesn't work at all.  IMHO Forget about restrictions

Comment: @ Serge, 1) so which are the methods needs CORS? 2) Though header restrictions applied using  .WithHeaders("CustomHeader1", "CustomHeader2") CORS working for **"CustomHeader11234"** as well without honoring the header restriction.

Comment: @ Serge, Also I'm not seeing these headers (Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: CustomHeader1) in the response which are enabled as part CORS enabling

Answer (score 0):

In .Net-Core 1.1, you need add

```
app.UseCors(builder => builder
    .AllowAnyOrigin()
    .WithMethods("POST")
    .WithHeaders("CustomHeader1", "CustomHeader2")
);
```

before calling app.UseMvc() and app.UseStaticFiles().

---

**Suggestion 1** :

If your webapp is hosting on IIS, please check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53280377/7687666). If you
are in the development stage, please the order in your Startup.cs file.

**Suggestion 2** :

If it still not work, please generate publish file and check if there is a web.config file generated.

**Suggestion 3** :

It is recommended to code according to [the official examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-1.1), the official codes are all tested and can save a lot of time.

Comment: @ jason pan, this works but **can't able to restrict** CORS using .WithMethods("POST")
    .WithHeaders("CustomHeader1", "CustomHeader2") what would be the issue?

Comment: @191180rk Is your program deployed?

Comment: @ jason pan, at present Im verifying it using IISexpress from local once the local testing passed later it will be deployed to Azure ServiceFabric

Comment: @191180rk Referring to suggestion 2, check whether the release file contains web.config. In addition, if you are testing locally, please refer to the link above to modify it.

Comment: @191180rk https://davidsekar.com/asp-net/cors-development-in-localhost