# CORS Access-Control-Allow-Origin in Angular/C# project

Tags: c#, angular

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/spECC.png)

I get this error:
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://localhost:7218/api/User/Login. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing). Status code: 404.

Angular:

```
public headers = new HttpHeaders()
  .set('content-type', 'application/text')
  .set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');

  Login(){
    this.http.options("https://localhost:7218/api", {headers: this.headers})
    this.http.post("https://localhost:7218/api/User/Login", new LoginDto(this.login, this.password), {
      headers: this.headers
    }).subscribe(response => console.log(response))
  }
```

C#:

```
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(name: "localhost",
        policy =>
        {
            policy.AllowAnyOrigin()
            .AllowAnyHeader()
            .AllowAnyMethod();
        });
});
builder.Services.AddResponseCaching();
builder.Services.AddDataProtection();
builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddDbContext<DataBaseContext>(options => 
    options.UseMySql(config.GetConnectionString("DbConnection"), ServerVersion.AutoDetect(config.GetConnectionString("DbConnection")))
    );

builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

builder.Services.AddSingleton<ISessionMiddleware, SessionMiddleware>();

builder.Services.AddTransient<IUserService, UserService>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<IProductService, ProductService>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<IActionHistoryService, ActionHistoryService>();

var app = builder.Build();

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseRouting();
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllers().RequireCors("localhost");
});

app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseCors("localhost");
```

I tried adding headers to angular, to the post request, to the options request, content-type/json, nothing works

Comment: It's giving you a hint in the error; "Status code: 404." That means it made a request, and the server replied, saying "nope. never heard of it." It is very unusual for a person to programmatically make an OPTIONS call. This call is usually made as part of a preflight check made as part of the CORS process, which is performed by the browser itself.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [404 for web.api cors OPTIONS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25553855/404-for-web-api-cors-options)

Comment: my order in Program.cs was wrong that was causing the problem. Now it's working thank you for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this problem with a real project.
There are two issues here. One **CORS** error and one **404** error.
If the only issue with your code was CORS, you shouldn't have gotten a 404 (not found) error.

Regarding the 404 error, maybe the issue is with the URL in the client fetch or routing in ASP.
Due to your limited information, it is not possible to say exactly where the issue is.
However, this issue is usually not difficult to solve.

But in the case of CORS, according to [Microsoft's official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-7.0), your issue is the order of middlewares. Update your code like this:

```cs
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseCors("localhost");

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllers().RequireCors("localhost");
});
```

I hope it was useful.